# EVITAR ACCESO HASTA VERIFICAR EMAIL LARAVEL JETSTREAM

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Estoy probando la autenticación por defecto de Laravel y Jetstream. Mi duda es cuando un usuario se registra y directamente le redirige a su dashboard personal.

¿Se puede evitar ese acceso hasta que el usuario verifique su cuenta de correo electrónico?

Salu2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si, es posible limitar el acceso a páginas específicas a los usuarios que no han verificado su correo, para eso se utiliza el `->middleware('verified')` que puedes agregar a las rutas que deseas "proteger", para poder acceder a esas rutas los usuarios necesariamente tendrán que estar verificados

Te dejo un URL a un [tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/laravel-8-email-verification/) que muestra como limitar acceso a usuarios que no han verificado su correo electrónico (El tutorial está en inglés, pero es muy bueno y paso a paso)

Además, el tutorial utiliza jetstream así que se aplica perfectamente a tu caso